# The bool variable isn't updating?

Tags: flutter, dart

**The error isn't getting set to true, why so. Even after using setState.**

```
class _OtpState extends State<Otp> {
  bool error = false;

  OTPApi(String phoneNumber, String otp) async {
    
    if (user.StatusCode == 0) {
      KEY = user.Data!["CustomerKey"];
      await prefs.setString('KEY', KEY!);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        error = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

**API function. ERROR: The following _CastError was thrown while calling onChanged:
Null check operator used on a null value**

```
OTPApi(PhoneNumber!, pin).then((value) => {
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return error
                              ? const AlertDialog(
                                  title: Text("Verification Code"),
                                  content: Text('wrong otp'),
                                )
                              : const Loading();
                        })
                  });
            },
```

Comment: Are you sure program go to else? take a print

Comment: debug your program as your program is not going to else part

Comment: yes, else is running, so does if.

Comment: is bool error definition in build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error` is not set to `true`. Because the program isn't executing the function.
Because the part to focus here is the error , `Null check operator used on a null value`.

The meaning of the error is `!` operator is used on `Null value`

This error is shown because the `phoneNumber` is `null` for some reason.
Because of which the `OTPApi` function is not executing and it throws exception and comes out of execution.

Check the phoneNumber is not null before calling the function.This should fix your problem

Or

Change
`OTPApi(String phoneNumber, String otp)` to `OTPApi(String? phoneNumber, String otp)`

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks the error was i was setting the error to true in else, but nowhere updating it to false after else makes it true. So if i enter wrong otp the error is true but again if i entered the otp right there is no way to set it false.

Comment: Okay, but the question you asked was not  specific. So according to the code . I suggested the answer. If the answer is helpful . Mark it as tick. So that it helps others